# Work Complexity of Parallel Implementation of Histogram

Tags: c++, histogram, complexity-theory

I have successfully drawn up an implementation of a Histogram to be used in a CUDA based environment. 
What I have trouble understanding is what the work complexity of the algorithm would be.

I can say that the serial implementation complexity would be linear - O(n) where n = number of inputs based on the fact that we must loop through all inputs at-least once.

The implementation would:

- Split the measurements into groups
- Pass each group of measurements to a separate thread
- Compute a local histogram in each thread
- Reduce them to a global histogram

Would I have to work out the complexity of each step and merge?

Comment: Is your histogram computationally bound or IO bound? (usually it is the later)... Unless you can get a higher IO bandwidth to a GPU than to a single core you may find that you can get decent performance on a single core just using SIMD. It is not uncommon to get just under 1600 MB/second IO in raw IO, and adding the histogram end up with getting ~900 MB/second. Moving data back-n-forth to the GPU is usually the bottleneck on a GPU, and in this case the operations are minimal, so it may be a suboptimal case for selecting a GPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should calculate complexity for each step and take the biggest. In you case, all steps are linear, thus whole algorithm's complexity is linear.